# How to populate UILabel text with Strings fetched from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have some strings in a Parse class I would like to fetch and populate some UILabel's text with:

[image]

I implemented the following method in a custom class to query these string:

```
class Book: NSObject {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Books")
    var titleString: String!


    func fetchTitleString(){
        query.whereKeyExists("Title")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) book Titles.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [String] {
                    for object in objects {
                        self.titleString = object
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the UILabels I need to populate are in a detailViewController that gets pushed to the view in a `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath` when a cell is selected. here's that code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        var books : Array<Book>!

        let book = self.books[indexPath.row]
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController

            controller.titleSelected = book.titleString
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

        println("user tapped on thumbnail # \(indexPath.row)")

    }
```

that `titleSelected` String variable represents one of the UILabels text in my detailViewController. It would populate that labels text with whatever string object is grabbed from my parse query.. however its just blank when I run. What should I do or adjust to achieve what I am looking to do?

**UPDATE**

here is my detailViewController:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, ARNImageTransitionZoomable {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    var titleSelected: String!

    deinit {
        println("deinit DetailViewController")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.titleLabel.text = titleSelected

    }
```

Comment: Do you have code in the detail controller that sets the label's text to the value in `titleSelected`?  If so, where is it done?  (If not, why not?)

Comment: yes I do, check updated question @PhillipMills

Comment: its done in the viewWillAppear

Comment: I suggest setting breakpoints on the three lines where you assign the string and see what the values are as it runs.  (`self.titleString = object`, `controller.titleSelected = book.titleString`, `self.titleLabel.text = titleSelected`)  If it's good for some but not all, that would be a clue.

Comment: its giving a nil value to all the string variables, but i know for a fact the query is correct because i tested in a navigation item function, and every time i selected the navigation item, the console would println my two objects back in parse @PhillipMills

Comment: @MikeStrong your query may be correct, but look what your doing, you setting 1 string `self.titleString` to multiple objects, instead of setting multiple titleStrings to multiple objects in the loop. the first thing you should take care of is your `for object in objects` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you are casting PFObject as String to early in this line

```
 if let objects = objects as? [String]
```

Change this to

```
 if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
 {
   for oneObj in objects
   {
    var titleFromParse = oneObj["Title"] as! String
       // then do whatever you want with titleFromParse
       // for example insert to array:  self.books.append(titleFromParse)
         // reloadData() for the collectionView
   }

 }
```

And also I don't think this line is necessary

```
 query.whereKeyExists("Title")
```

And also I believe you should declare this line globally

```
var books: Array<book>!
```

**Answer** 
Remove  the query function from the NSObject class**

```
 func fetchTitleString()
{
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Books")
     query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil
        {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject]
            {
                 print("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) book Titles.")

                    for oneObj in objects
                    {
                            let titleFromParse = oneObj["Title"] as! String
                            let SingleBook = Book()
                            SingleBook.titleString = titleFromParse
                            self.arrayOfStrings.append(SingleBook)

                    } 


               }
        }

        else
        {
            // Log details of the failure 
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: so if i want to set my `var titleString: String!` value to the value of the titleFromParse string fetched from the query, where should i do so in that method?

Comment: **var books: Array<Book>!** this should be global variable because once you are done querying data, those data could be insert into the array then you could populate all cell in your collection

Comment: i actually have done so, I just altered the code in the question slightly to make the question less elongated , can we [continue this in a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88957/parse-and-strings) real quick?